# parallax.js automatically slide onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, parallax.js

I am using this jQuery plugin on a website: http://stolksdorf.github.com/Parallaxjs/

I am trying to achieve an effect where when a slide is navigated to, it automatically moves onto another slide once it has loaded - think of it as a transition slide.

For example:

```
parallax.transition.onload=function(){
    parallax.citymid.show();
};
```

This code shows the city mid slide once the transition slide has loaded.

However:

```
parallax.transition.onload=function(){
    parallax.citymid.bottom();
};
```

This does not make city mid slide in from the bottom as it would if it was called from a button.

Does anyone know whow I can make this work, or at least find a work around for it? I have contacted the developer of the plugin but to no avail.

Many thanks,
Oli

Comment: in jquery, you can programatically simulate a button being clicked.
Ex HTML:
<button id='special_button' value='click me' />
Ex JS in $(document).ready()

$("#special_button").click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using transition callbacks, everything works as it should.

```
parallax.pageB.right(function(){
parallax.pageC.right();
});
```

Call this bit of code while on pageA and it will slide in pageB from the right, and as soon as it's done it will slide in pageC. I've tested this and it works flawlessly.